# Table organization using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, savechanges

I am trying to organise tables in my database using Entity Framework Core.

Roughly speaking, I have the following entities:

```
class Book{
  int Id {get; set;}
  List<Chapter> Chapters {get; set;}
}

class Chapter{
  int Id {get; set;}
  List<Page> Pages {get; set;}
}

class Article{
  int Id {get; set;}
  List<Section> Sections {get; set;}
}

class Section{
  int Id {get; set;}
  List<Page> Pages {get; set;}
}

class Page{
  int Id {get; set;}
}
```

In my class that derives from DbContext I create the following tables:

```
DbSet<Book> Book {get; set;}

DbSet<Article> Article {get; set;}

DbSet<Section> Section {get; set;}

DbSet<Chapter> Chapter {get; set;}
```

The problem is that I cannot save any records that contain nonempty Page collections into this database because each Page resord gets two foreign keys - SectionId and ChapterId, and when I try to put a Book record which contains Chapter records which in turn contain some Page records into that database, it complains that SectionId cannot be null for Page records.

What are possible solutions to this apart from creating two separate similar Page entities, say SectionPage and ChapterPage?

**UPDATE:**
In OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) method I also add the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Chapter>()
             .HasMany(ch => ch.Pages)
             .WithOne()
             .IsRequired()
       .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
             .HasMany(s => s.Pages)
             .WithOne()
             .IsRequired()
       .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: Who complains - EF or database?

Comment: I get an exception in the code which says that a null value cannot be inserted into the table, hence the insertion of the appropriate record fails. exception occurs after I reach dbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: I'm asking because by convention the one-to-many relationships are *optional*, so if you have created the db from EF model, the FK property should allow `null`.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev I did add the one-to-many relationship using ModelBuilder in OnModelCreating method of dbContext in fact. If I remove this, will everything work properly (meaning not my particular case, but the database in general)?

Comment: Can you post the fluent configuration for `Section` -> `Page` relationship?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev I updated the question

Comment: Thanks. You might consider removing both `IsRequired()`, thus allowing FKs to be `null`s, which seem to be appropriate for such design.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Thank you very much!